# Flask use variable outside function

Tags: python, flask

I need to pass the "card" variable to another python script once received, therefore I need to get the "card" variable out of the index() function somehow.

How do I do it? It's printing to the console & returning "card" already, but don't know where the return goes. As I can't just print(index()). Thanks

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/bridge', methods=['POST']) #when receiving JSON
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json = request.json 
        card = json['data']
        print(card) #print received card string
        return card

print(card) #need to print it here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8400, threads=8) #_quiet=True disable waitress warnings
```

Comment: You need to do whatever needs to be done with `card` from *within* `index()` - launch this other script, or whatever.  That's the one place in the program where you know that a value has actually been received.

Comment: I can write it to the file there & then read it with another script, but believe there must be some smarter solution.

Comment: You could pass the data as a command-line parameter to the script when you launch it, or write it to the script's standard input.  Or better yet, put the code in *this* script rather than a separate one, and just call the function with `card` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When using a route to decorate a Flask function, it maps that function entirely to that endpoint under specific parameters you set. When a client sends a http POST request to /bridge, `index()` is run and the variable `card` is returned to the original client formatted by Flask into a http plaintext response. Thus, these functions only get called when accessed by a http client.

Now, to answer your question specifically, to *pass the "card" variable to another python script once received* we need to call this script from inside the function index() as that's the only function that actually runs when the endpoint is accessed. Let's make a thread from the inside to prevent python from blocking the return response also.

```py
import os
from threading import Thread

def wrapper(card):
    #your code to run python script here
    os.system(f"python script.py -c {card}") # card as sys.argv

@app.route('/bridge', methods=['POST']) #when receiving JSON
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json = request.json 
        card = json['data']
        print(card) #print received card string
        Thread(target=wrapper, args=(card,))
        return card
```

On an important note, **this is not a scaleable solution** and fully fledged out process. Starting this many python threads is not a good idea, and also "passing a python variable into another script" sounds like very bad practice in this situation. It would be best to turn this script into an object or function, import it and globally define it in your Flask app, then directly call it from `index()` to handle all the operations within that function. That's beyond the scope of the original question though.